# Which onLoad Fires First?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In the context of the DOM, does `body.onLoad` trigger before `window.onload` or '[element].onload'?

My thinking is, I want a script to execute before the whole page has finished loading, but after certain DOM elements have.

Basically, as soon as there's an element X, I want to get the content of X and start an asynchronous job using that content, but the only way I have to get the content of X is to wait for X to load because I'm working on an extension. So could `X.onload` be considered to reliably trigger before `window.onload` or `body.onload`?

Specifically I'm working on a Chrome extension, so for the time being if the order is different in Safari or IE, I don't necessarily need to know, although I'm always interested in the why and how.

JS-Perf test [here](http://jsperf.com/load-events). They are inconclusive because the image is cached before the tests are run, making a 2MP image load faster than an empty DIV.

Open to any suggestions on how this could be meaningfully tested.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you spent any time looking into this? Have you tried it out to see which in which order they occur for different browsers (or at least Chrome)?

Comment: Have you checked [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded)? User can't notice a gap of few milliseconds, which it takes to _parse_ HTML between `X` and `</body>`.

Comment: @Teemu It's not a few milliseconds. Some of the pages may take seconds to load, and we could already have retrieved our info before render if we can start early enough.

Comment: Most likely it is, parsing HTML doesn't take much time, rendering is totally different process, which starts _after_ `DOMContentLoaded` has been triggered. Why don't you test it, you'll see...

Comment: i think you're misguided about what 'onload' means. Unlike in microsoft's WPF or in some other frameworks, onlad triggers only for a few tags that depends on the loading of an external file, it cannot be used on others just to know when they are ready. (list is here for instance : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp). If i were you i would launch all async job as early as possible, and when all jobs are done + window loaded, i would update everything.

Comment: Test results are useless: http://jsperf.com/load-events image is cached so it loads fastest. It says an empty div is loading slower than a cached image.

Comment: @Teemu misunderstood, haven't used `DOMContentLoaded`. I'll look into that in the extension.Definitely need something faster than `window.onload` though. Thanks!

Comment: @JasonNichols In a Chrome extension, content scripts are injected somewhere between DOMContentLoaded and onload (called "document_idle"). If you want to run asap, use `"run_at": "document_start"` (fired when document tree consists of `<html>` only), or `"run_at": "document_end"` (similar to DOMContentLoaded)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per input from Teemu and RobW, (as well as supporting documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) removing the event listener and running the code inline in a script set in the manifest to `"run_at":"document_end"` will achieve the desired result.

For others who might have this problem in manifest.json

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["TARGET_URL"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
          "run_at" : "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

in myscript.js:

```
function reqListener () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
}

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "yourFile.txt", true);
oReq.send();
```

This gaurantees execution after DOM parse, but before child element load, starting our AJAX request much earlier. (This is obviously not production code, just an example code pattern for others to follow).

Thanks for all the comments!